# Reading data from JSON file having multiple objects and arrays and display in card carousel in angular 7

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, angular7

I want to display data dynamically in multiple card carousels (ngx-owl-carousel) in **ANGULAR 7**, for that I am trying to read data from a JSON file having multiple objects and array and I'm using service to achieve this. But I'm not getting how  to display data dynamically for multiple objects in cards. Thanks for help.

The code is as below:

```
**test.component.html**
<owl-carousel [options]="cardOptions" [items]="cards" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding','row']">

<div class="recommended item" style="border-radius: 4px;margin-left:2.5%;border-bottom:4px solid #12C079;height:AUTO%" *ngFor="let card of carouselCards;"> 
  <div style="border-radius: 4px;margin-bottom:4%;">
       <img src="assets/ESSENTIALS.png" alt="Avatar" >
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#fff;padding:101px 5px 5px 5px ;border-radius: 4px">  
          <p style="color:black;font-size:14px"> {{card.title}}</p>
         <p>{{card.description}}</p>
         <img class="banner" src="{{card.image}}" alt="Avatar" style=" ">

   <img class="coin" src="assets/coins.png" alt="Avatar" ><p class="rs"><b>180</b></p>

           </div>
       </div>
```

```
**test.component.ts**


import { CardService } from './../card.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
import {OwlCarousel} from 'ngx-owl-carousel';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs';



@Component({
 selector: 'app-test',
 templateUrl: './test.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
 })
 export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

 public carouselCards=[];
 cardOptions = {
 items: 4, 
 dots: true, 
 nav: true,
 mouseDrag: true,
 loop: true,
 slideBy: 3
};


constructor(private _card: CardService) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this._card.getCards() // http request
.subscribe(data =>{
  this.carouselCards = data['this.carouselCards'];
  console.log(carouselCards);
}); // observable response




}
```

}

```
**card.service**


import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';




@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CardService {

 private _urlCardFile = 'assets/carousel-cards.json';


constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

 getCards(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this._urlCardFile).map(res => res.json());
  }
 }  



JSON FILe:
[
"cards":{ 
    "featured":
    [

        {
            "title" : "card 1",
            "description" :"Facebook has a customer chat widget",
            "image" : "./assets/img/sample.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title" : "card 2",        
            "description" :"this is sample course",
            "image" : "./assets/img/sample.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title" : "card 3",
            "description" :"this is sample course",
            "image" : "./assets/img/sample.jpg"    
        },
        {
            "title" : "card 4",        
            "description" :"this is sample course",
            "image" : "./assets/img/sample.jpg"   
        },
        {
            "title" : "card 5",        
            "description" :"this is sample course",
            "image" : "./assets/img/sample.jpg"   
        },
        {
            "title" : "card 6",        
            "description" :"this is sample course",
            "image" : "./assets/img/sample.jpg"   
        },
        {
            "title" : "card 7",        
            "description" :"this is sample course",
            "image" : "./assets/img/sample.jpg"   
        }

    ],

"explore":
    [  
            {
                "title" : "card 1",
                "image" : "./assets/BIM ESSENTIALS.png"
            },
            {
                "title" : "card 2",        
                "image" : "./assets/sample.png"
            },
            {
                "title" : "card 3",
                "image" : "./assets/sample.png"    
            },
            {
                "title" : "card 4",        
                "image" : "./assets/img.png"   
            },
            {
                "title" : "card 5",        
                "image" : "./assets/img.png"   
            }
    ]







    }
]
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but perhaps the [items] binding on <owl-carousel> should be `carouselCards` instead of `cards`?

Comment: Thanks, yeah  that's carouselCards,I forgot to modify it.. that displays carousel when there is data for single object in json file, But I want to display for multiple objects here in above file it's : featured and explore